# Why didn't the Geass work on Kallen the second time?

Tags: code-geass

Why didn't the geass work on Kallen the second time Lelouch used it?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfgyr91rr9Y

Answer (score 9):

Because Lelouch's Geass can only be used on a given person once, ever. This is one of the fundamental limitations of his Geass. Indeed, it is when his second Geass on Kallen fails that Lelouch realizes that this limitation exists.

Comment: actually Lelouch realizes the limitations when he tried it on that teacher using his Geass to ask for the subject on the next test. i do believe he confirms this between then and his reunion with C.C after some experiments